# Woocomerce product attribute field value missalignment

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I got a woocomerce product attribute field value which is misaligned:
[Bottom attribute field value should be under attribute title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NJEC.png)

I can see that alignment of that block is set to left, but does not seem to work
[text alignment css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqgu0.png)

Does anyone know what to look at?

Looked at css using browser, that actually looks correct.
Looking for suggestions what to look at

Comment: can you share the whole css code? or a link to your site to see it? Without all the code related to the issue is hard to see if it is having a conflict with other code.

Comment: https://hugabook.eu/produktas/daiktadeze-kudikio-daiktams-mazesne/

Comment: I would like attribute field values be listed below attribute description as it is for the first one (the upper one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert, but I think you can add the same css property to the row.

```
margin-bottom: 10px; 
display: block;
```

This is how it looks.

[image]